# How can i change the options of my drawerNavigator in React Native before and after loged in

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation

**Before Login i have these options.**

Home,
Free Services,
Signals,
Contact Us,
Login,
Signup

**i want to  add more and also change some options after login**

Home,
Free Services,
Paid Services,
Free Signals,
Paid Signals,
Contact us,
Logout

Please Resolve my issue how can i do this.

Answer (score 0):

When your react native app has authentication you should use SwitchNavigator.

Read this page from the react navigation documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html

Before login you use the 'Auth' stack and after login you use the 'App' stack. Each stack has its own navigator. The AuthLoadingScreen checks if the user is logged in and uses the appropriate stack.